# hybris populators and converters concept and their relationship

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Can someone please explain the concept of **converters** and **populators** used in the Hybris? I was going through the concept of AddOns in Hybris but one of the points said "You can plug populators into existing converters without having to redefine them" after we use `AddOns` in Hybris commerce accelerator? So I thought it`s better to understand these concepts first.

Comment: In short, Converters are collection of populators where each populator play individual role to populate part of DTO. Hybris strongly recommend that you should not write concrete converter (without populator). Atleast one populator should bind with converter to populate its DTO. And Its easy to plug and play with it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In a nutshell, converters are used to create data objects (DTOs) out of (mostly) model objects and populators are used to fill in the dtos.

You'll find a pretty good documentation of both concepts here for version 5:
https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Converters+and+Populators

Here for version 6:
https://help.hybris.com/6.0.0/hcd/8b937ff886691014815fcd31ff1de47a.html

(If you don't have wiki access yet, you should get it as the wiki and the experts forum at https://experts.hybris.com are two essential resources to get a lot of answers from).

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Hybris converters are made out of a list of populatiors for a certain type, this allows you to keep a certain modularity in the way you create a populator for a certain type without having to give too much responsibility to a single one.

Besides from that, you can use a configurable converter in which you can define though constants passed through which allow to execute certain populators this is used in for example the product list in which you don't want to populate all the fields of the product.

finally I also recommend taking a look into the hybris help page and decompiling hybris sources to have a better understanding of their implementation.

hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You should create object firstly for populator while converter creates target object and then populates it automatically.

```
//converter example   
Target target = targetConverter.convert(source);
List<Target> targetList = sourceList.toStream().map(s->targetConverter.convert(s));

//Populator example    
Target target = new Target();    
targetPopulator.populate(source, target);
```